# Calculating SAVI - TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType

Tags: python, numpy, infrared

I'm doing this to calculate SAVI, ir is infrared band and r is red band, c is the constant that I set 0.5:

```
#SAVI - Soil Adjusted Vegetation Index
#SAVI = (ir - red) * (1 + c)/(ir + red + c)
c=0.5
ir = (img[:,:,0]).astype('float')
r = (img[:,:,2]).astype('float')
savi = np.zeros(r.size)
savi = np.true_divide(np.multiply(np.subtract(ir,r),(1 + c)), np.add(ir,r,c))
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-16dbc9db64d2> in <module>()
      3 r = (img[:,:,2]).astype('float')
      4 savi = np.zeros(r.size)
----> 5 savi = np.true_divide(np.multiply(np.subtract(ir,r),(1 + c)), np.add(ir,r,c))

TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The [`numpy.add`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.add.html) function can accept only two array-like parameters. As long as "*ir*" and "*r*" are numpy arrays but "*c*" is a scalar, you can sum up directly the former and use them as the first input, as follows:

```
savi = np.true_divide(np.multiply(np.subtract(ir,r),(1 + c)), np.add(ir+r, c))
```

Or if you prefer, just sum them up, as numpy will handle broadcasting the "*c*" value:

```
savi = np.true_divide(np.multiply(np.subtract(ir,r),(1 + c)), ir+r+c)
```